# How can I keep a text wrap object working in front of a text symbol?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols, text-wrap

I have an object set as text wrap in front of a text box which works fine. As soon as I drag the text into the Symbols panel to create a symbol, the text wrap function stops working.

Seems like a bug with Illustrator. Anyone know of a workaround or fix?

Comment: Hi jonny, welcome to GDSE. The text wrap it's is applied to the object and is the one that causes it. If you move the text outside of that object, of course you will lose the wrap because it is no longer with the object that produced the wrapping. Or maybe there's a wrong info at your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonny:

Illustrator text wrap is very layer and group sensitive: the text-wrap causing object must be directly above the text frame for the wrap to work - your making a symbol of the text prevents that from occurring.

If you break the Symbol link whilst watching the layers palette, you will notice the symbol expands as a text frame in a group... if you then ungroup it, so that the text is sitting directly beneath the wrap-causing objects in the layer stack, the text starts wrapping as expected.

You can make a symbol in which your wrap causing objects are part of the symbol with the text, and this wraps correctly too, because by Illustrator's internal logic, the layer-order and group isolation still allows the correct relationship for text wrap to work.

I wouldn't call this a bug, in all honesty, more like a specific workflow / order of operations quirk.

Hope this helps.